# Vagrant custom box metadata.json file

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-provision

I have a custom box named package.box. I get this error when trying to vagrant up, vagrant box add. I created a metadata.json file with different configurations but with no luck. I don't understand this message. I use virtualbox for provisioning.

I don't understand the documentation on their website regarding metadata.json file.

> The "metadata.json" file for the box 'package.box' was not found.
>   Boxes require this file in order for Vagrant to determine the
>   provider it was made for. If you made the box, please add a
>   "metadata.json" file to it. If someone else made the box, please
>   notify the box creator that the box is corrupt. Documentation for
>   box file format can be found at the URL below:
>   https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html

The package.box lives in am empty directory. Next to it I put this metadata.json file:

```
{
    "description": "long box description",
    "short_description": "short box description",
    "name": "company/developer-environment",
    "versions": [{
        "version": "1",
        "status": "active",
        "description_html": "<p>Dev Environment</p>",
        "description_markdown": "Dev Environment",
        "providers": [{
            "name": "virtualbox",
            "url": "./package.box"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I use a ubuntu 16.04 system, vagrant 1.8.5, virtualbox 5.0.26.

Answer (score 4):

the `package.box` file is a zip file of your VM, the `metadata.json` file must not be next the the package.box file but inside it.

so store the metadata file next to the VM file before you package the box, something like

```
.
|-- box-disk1.vmdk
|-- box.ovf
|-- metadata.json
```

so when you run `vagrant package` it will include the metadata file as part of the box file.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine after I repackaged the box. I don't know why but it worked. The metadata file existed in the first place there.

Comment: Since he gave you the answer. Don't hesitate mark his response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is not an answer, but a follow up question.

This looks exactly like the problem that I'm having. As I cannot fetch the metadata.json from Artifactory.

How can I pack my metadata.json into my .box file?

I have my box created in two steps.

First:
Base Image which produces a `*.vmdk` and `*.ovf` file

Done with

```json
"post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "artifice",
      "files": [
        "builds/{{.BuildName}}-{{.Provider}}-centos7.vmdk",
        "builds/{{.BuildName}}-{{.Provider}}-centos7.ovf"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "vagrant",
      "keep_input_artifact": true,
      "provider_override": "virtualbox"
    }
  ]
```

Second:
I install my web-application into the image, and generate the `*.box` file.

Done with:

```json
"post-processors": [
    [
      {
        "output": "builds/devbox.box",
        "type": "vagrant"
      }
    ]
  ]
```